# Did Cad Bane get his ship back or did he just get a new one?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In [S2E03 of Clone Wars, Children of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Force), Cad Bane was captured along with his [Rogue Class star fighter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue-class_Porax-38_starfighter) by the Jedi. The ship was definitely in the hands of Republic forces, as Anakin and Ahsoka were shown extracting information from its systems.

[image: Anakin, Ahsoka, and R2D2 working on Bane's Rogue Class fighter, in the Clone Wars S2E03]

At the end of the episode, Bane escaped custody via an escape pod, leaving his ship in Republic hands.

However, in [S3E09, Hunt for Ziro](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hunt_for_Ziro), Bane was shown using a Rogue Class in his pursuit of Ziro.

[image: Cad Bane exiting his Rogue Class fighter on Nal Hutta, Clone Wars S3E09]

Was this the same ship that he had confiscated from him by the Republic? And if so, how did he retrieve it?

Comment: good question - with CW, it's always a good idea to check the official chronological ordering of the episodes vs the broadcast and streaming order. Early seasons had episodes all out of order. In this case though, seems like these episodes are in the correct timeline order - https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-chronological-episodeorder

Comment: What @NKCampbell said

Comment: @NKCampbell - That makes a lot of sense. Do you want to make that into an answer?

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question of 'how did he get his ship back / is that the same ship' - I was hoping it would be a case of episodes out of order but alas :")

Comment: @NKCampbell - I think your assumption was right and that the official chronological order is in fact incorrect. I think Hostage Crisis and Hunt for Ziro should both have occurred prior to Holocron Heist.

Comment: that was my hope - but the official 'chronologically correct' viewing order lists the Hunt for Ziro as happening well after Children of the Force, so I think it's a 'we don't know how he got it back' type of situation

Comment: @NKCampbell - but I think we have found a glitch in their "correct" story order.

Comment: not necessarily - could just be a gap in the story and he did get it back. Cad Bane is awesome...

Comment: No answer in _The Clone Wars: Incredible Vehicles_, just a profile of the fighter class. It's possible this is covered in https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars:_Episode_Guide but I don't have it.